# Energy conservation vs force equivalence in charged block spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics

Consider the following question
[image]

If you use energy conservation, you’ll get option B which is correct. But if you equate the forces in the fully stretched equilibrium position, you’ll get option A. Why are we getting two answers for different methods; and why is the method 2 wrong?

$Kr=\frac{q²}{4 π \epsilon (2r)²}$

(By equating force, spring force=coulumbic repulsion force)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the electric repulsive force due to charges is greater than the tension force produced by the spring.

As the charges move away, the repulsive force decreases whilst the tension force increases.

There will come a time when those two forces are equal **however** the charges will have kinetic energy because they are moving when the net force on them is zero.
[This is where you went wrong by equating forces as the charges have kinetic energy.]

Thus the charges will overshoot that position and carry on moving until the decrease in electric potential energy is equal to the increase in spring potential energy.
At that point the charges will be stationary with the tension force greater than the electric repulsive force.

The next part of the motion will be the charges moving towards one another.